# Separable space admits a metric such that collection of open balls is locally finite

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, separable-spaces

In the article [When the collection of ε-balls is locally finite](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166864101002516), in the second paragraph of Introduction, it is said that:

> Each separable metric space $X$ admits a metric $d$ such that, the collection $\{B(x,\epsilon):x\in X\}$ of all $\epsilon$-balls is finite for every $\epsilon>0$.

I don't understand how this collection is finite if the number of elements in $X$ is infinite. Can somebody explain it?

Comment: Simply put, the construction of that metric must be such that $B(x,\epsilon)=B(y,\epsilon)$ happens very often even when $x\ne y$.

Comment: As @HagenvonEitzen mentions, this is a very strong property but possible. For example, I believe any ultrametric has this property as long as the space has finite diameter (don't quote me on that).

Comment: The title of the question says *locally* finite, not finite. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

Sets do not have duplicate elements so that $B_d(x,\varepsilon)$ could be the same set as $B_d(y, \varepsilon)$ for many pairs $x \neq y$ and then this counts as just one set in $\mathcal{B}_d(\varepsilon)$.

And eventually the result is about the collection $\{B_d(x, \varepsilon): x \in X\}$ being **locally** finite, which is much weaker than finite (but implies finite in a compact space). It means that every point has a neighbourhood that only intersects finitely many different elements of that set of balls. But this condition is equivalent to many stronger and weaker variants of that same condition (star-finite etc.).

It's a nice paper BTW at first glance; I didn't know it yet. It turns out that quite a few metric spaces admit such a metric.